# replace function used as default for table

Tags: postgresql

I have function, that generates uniq IDs for some tables (about 400 tables), eg:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   id bigint DEFAULT get_unique_id(),
   ...
)
```

I need to add optional attribute into that method. 
Now I can create new method with the same name and optional attiribute

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_unique_id(swithattribute integer DEFAULT (-1)) ...
```

but I want to have only one method with this name.

So I need to replace the orginal one, but if I try to remove the original function get_unique_id(), postgres throw me and error:

```
ERROR:  cannot drop function get_unique_id() because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  default for table my_table column id depends on function get_unique_id()
default for table my_table2 column id depends on function get_unique_id()
...
```

Is there any easy way how to add optional attribute into already existing function?

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
begin;
alter table my_table alter column id set default -1;
create or replace function get_unique_id...; --insert new function definition here
alter table my_table alter column id set default get_unique_id();
commit;
```

but probably table exclusive lock is needed so it can block queries for a while.

If there are many tables you can use query:

```
select 'alter table '||quote_ident(table_schema)||'.'||quote_ident(table_name)||' alter column '||quote_ident(column_name)||' set default -1;' from information_schema.columns where column_default='get_unique_id()';
```

to generate needed `alter` statements.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but there are about 400 tables that are using this function.

Comment: @JakubMichalko, I've added statement to generate needed `ddl`. I guess you are looking for something more elegant but I doubt if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I invent some hack-y, but elegant and working solution. I created the needed function as temporary

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_unique_tmp(arg int default 0) ...
```

and then I changed the original one (args and src) in PG catalog by this temporary function

```
update pg_catalog.pg_proc 
set proargtypes=x.proargtypes, proargnames=x.proargnames, proargdefaults=x.proargdefaults,prosrc=x.prosrc,pronargs=x.pronargs,pronargdefaults=x.pronargdefaults
from (select * from pg_catalog.pg_proc p where p.proname='get_unique_tmp') x
where pg_catalog.pg_proc.proname='get_unique_id'
```

but I am not sure about it's correctness.